# How to load 500M records in utf16le text encoding into Mysql 5.7 Aurora?

Tags: mysql

I'm importing a subset of a huge CSV via workbench (MySql 5.7 Aurora)to:

quickly generate the columns

Then i'll load the data from S3 using LOAD DATA INFILE

However, the data contains many languages and the format is utf16le

When i try to import in workbench with uft16 i get

```
"charmap codec can't decode"..
```

If i extract a few rows from the CSV using powershell:

```
Get-Content .\data.csv | select -First 10 | Out-File ./test.csv
```

Then load test.csv using uft16 i get:

```
"could not determine delimiter"
```

Even if i set it as the default "comma" it doesn't work.

What's the best way to handle the multi language 500M record csv for import into MySQL?

Comment: Upload your CSV onto MySQL server. Then load it using LOAD DATA INFILE, but previously set all related charsets (server, connection, table and so on) to utf16le, and all related collations to utf16le_general_ci or utf16le_bin

Comment: I was reading in the documents for Mysql 5.7 that uft18le is not supported for important or load data infile? Can i load the data im one of the other utf16 encodings you mentioned without effecting the data? I'm really under pressure to get this working :(

Comment: Would you be able to give an example of this? I thought you cannot load data that has utf16le encoding?

It says you can't load data using "The ucs2, utf16, utf16le, and utf32 character sets"

Comment: True. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-restrictions.html *The ucs2, utf16, utf16le, and utf32 character sets have the following restrictions: .. It is currently not possible to use LOAD DATA to load data files that use these character sets.* If so test does your CSV can be connected as a table using [The CSV Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/csv-storage-engine.html). If possible then connect and copy the data using trivial INSERT .. SELECT.

Comment: Do you have any example how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean as "this"? attaching the data from CSV as a table? study the link I have provided above - it contains enough info.